# ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `protect_against_forgery?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails console, I want to test my mail sending functions with the command and a basic function: 
`UserMailer.send_test_mail(user).deliver_now`
but it returns me

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `protect_against_forgery?'
```

I searched for this but beginning in rails I don't really understand where my problem is.

`send_test_mail` function in UserMailer class :

```
def send_test_mail(user)
      @user = user
      mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "Test de mail")
    end
```

send_test_mail.erb :
`Hello, this is a test`

I saw people saying that code could help : 
`def protect_against_forgery?
      false
 end`

But I don't know where it should be inserted

Update : found out the error : I had some code in my app/views/layout/mailer.html.erb that made this error generated:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

If someone can explain what the problem is between this and my error , I would be grateful :)

Comment: Hello,  If your mailer was generated you should have a file 'app/helpers/mailer_name_helper.rb'. that is where you can put the protect_against_forgery code

Comment: Hi, my mailer is not generated because of this error, so I don't have the file you mention